# Increase maximal thumbnail size in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, images, thumbnails

I would like to inspect images in Windows Explorer on W7 in greater detail on a big screen. Thumbnails are by default limited to ~ 256x256 px. Is there a way to increase the upper bound or some 3rd party solution? Intensive googling didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The largest thumbnails supported in Windows Explorer are 256x256 pixels. Beyond that you need to use a 3rd party program like [ACDSee](http://www.acdsee.com/). In ACDSee, the size of the thumbnails in the thumbnail view is limited to 320 pixel. For larger thumbnails you can include this into your registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\40]
"MaxDisplayThumbSize"=dword:00000400
```

This gives the choice to move the thumbnail size slider from 25 up to 1024 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I actually meant 3rd party solution integrated into Windows Explorer. I currently use free [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.net)'s thumbnails app with thumbnails up to 800x800 and many additional powerful features.

Comment: `The largest thumbnails supported in Windows Explorer are 256x256 pixels.` How? Where? Why? It is hard-coded somewhere in `explorer.exe`? Maybe there's a way to hack it bigger. I really don't see why there should be any technical reason for it to not be possible to be bigger, the re-sizing algorithm should work just fine for bigger thumbnails, it's just a matter of hacking Explorer. Damn, now I have yet another project to add to my list. `ಠ_ಠ`